# Getting the Penultimate Record from a Table Sorted by Descending ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

We need to obtain the penultimate row of a table that is sorted by its ID in descending order, not by the date. Then, ensure that the table has unique date values. Finally, once the table is sorted with distinct dates, retrieve the second most recent record. How to achieve this?

```
create table mytable (id int, ForecastDate date);
insert into mytable values
(1,'2023-12-05'),(2,'2024-01-03'),(3,'2024-04-01'),(4,'2024-04-01'),(5,'2024-04-01');
```

Table:

| id | ForecastDate |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-12-05 |
| 2 | 2024-01-03 |
| 3 | 2024-04-01 |
| 4 | 2024-04-01 |
| 5 | 2024-04-01 |

from this table we need in the first step to sort out by its id. Then we need to have distinct dates. Why? The main aim is to get the second most recent record of the table, but with distinct dates.

The final result *must* show this record:  2024-01-03 which belongs to id 2 of mytable.

| id | ForecastDate |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 2024-01-03 |

I have tried with these 2 CTE, but unfortunately CTE does not enable the use of ORDER BY, and I do not want to use the TOP.

```
WITH DistinctForecastDate AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
          mytable.ForecastDate AS ForecastDate
    FROM
        mytable
   
   ORDER BY   mytable.id DESC
)

, RowNumberDate AS (
    SELECT DistinctForecastDate.ForecastDate AS ForecastDate
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RowNumber
    FROM DistinctForecastDate
)
SELECT RowNumberDate.DeliveryDate
FROM RowNumberDate 
WHERE RowNumberDate.RowNumber = 2
```

I have a fiddle here https://sqlfiddle.com/sql-server/online-compiler?id=97d0be8e-635e-44f1-8d4e-c8818e24e2a5

I have tried with another query but it delivers the wrong result (2023-12-05), as you can see in the fiddle:

How to get the 2024-01-03 value? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you think `ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)` does? But it doesn't order by anything thats for sure.

Comment: And you need to clarify, if you wish distinct dates, you can only choose a single id for duplicated dates, so which id would it be? i.e. do you want to keep 3 or 4 in your example?

Comment: I have tried with it, but it did not work. Unfortunately WITH CTE does not enable the use of the ORDER BY which would help a lot. The query I shared shows the logic:
1. sort the table by descending ID
2. get distinct values for date
3. get the second row of the final table.

Comment: But your query doesn't show whether you keep id 3 or 4, because your doesn't work that way. So please clarify.

Comment: for duplicated values, the ID does not matter, it can be any, providing we have the second most recent record of the table with distinct dates. :)

Comment: If you want `ROW_NUMBER()` to return values based on the dates have you considered ordering by those dates instead of `SELECT NULL`?

Comment: The spec is very unclear. What if the ID = 4 had date 2024-04-02, then in my opinion it should return that value if i understand your question correctly. If not, then i don't understand why sorting by ID even matters, just remove the duplicate dates and go to town

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you have stated you don't care which `Id` is kept in the case of duplicate ForecastDates, then just use a simple `GROUP BY` to remove duplicates, then use `ROW_NUMBER` as you were to find the second row.

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    -- Remove duplicate ForecastDates 
    SELECT min(id) id, ForecastDate
    FROM mytable
    GROUP BY ForecastDate
), cte2 AS (
    -- Find the second row
    SELECT *
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id DESC) rn
    FROM cte1
)
-- Filter out the second row
SELECT id, ForecastDate
FROM cte2
WHERE rn = 2;
```

Returns:

| id | ForecastDate |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 2024-01-03 |

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/cWg8qcOw)

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for! Many thanks, Dale. All the best.

Comment: Ah. I saw one use case where that query delivers the wrong value...
But I think it will be enough to substitute Min(id) by Max(id).  If you use these additional data:
(6,'2023-01-01'), (7,'2023-01-02'),(8,'2024-04-01');  you will see it will deliver 6 2023-01-01 and it should be 7,'2023-01-02'. WIth MAX(Id) it gives the correct value. 
So in case of duplicated values, MAX(Id) will guarantee that it will work for cases where the same duplicated dates are dispersed.

Comment: @graphene I specifically asked you in the comments which id you wanted when there was a duplicate and you said, I quote "for duplicated values, the ID does not matter, it can be any". Thats the reason you need to be 100% precise when asking your question.

Comment: You are right, Dale. However, while I was testing with several use cases, I came across with that one. So, max(id) solves the case. Your query was/is really very helpful. Many thanks. My bad I forgot that particular use case!

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly you want the row with the highest ID that is part of the group of rows with the second most recent date. In SQL Server 2012 there are a couple of options to do this which do not require a CTE:

1. Using `OFFSET` and `FETCH`

```
    DECLARE @SECOND_LAST_DATE AS DATE;
    SET @SECOND_LAST_DATE = (
        SELECT DISTINCT(ForecastDate)
        FROM mytable
        ORDER BY ForecastDate DESC
        OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
    );
    
    SELECT TOP 1 id, ForecastDate
    FROM mytable
    WHERE ForecastDate = @SECOND_LAST_DATE
    ORDER BY id DESC;
```

2. Using `DENSE_RANK`

```
    SELECT TOP 1 o.id, o.ForecastDate
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            i.id, i.ForecastDate 
            , DENSE_RANK() OVER (
                ORDER BY i.ForecastDate DESC
            ) AS Rank  
        FROM mytable i
    ) o
    WHERE o.Rank = 2
    ORDER BY o.id DESC;
```

Comment: Your first suggestion is way more complex than any of the others. Your second uses a sub-query which is in most cases identical to a CTE. Why are you trying to avoid a CTE anyway?

Comment: By more complex, do you mean time complexity? I'm not sure that's the case, happy to be corrected though. A CTE is a top level statement which isn't supported in all situations, for example in an EF Core query with Includes, whereas by using `DENSE_RANK()` you can achieve the same thing in a single select which would be supported. Mainly I answered to show there are alternative ways of achieving the same result which could potentially be useful for future readers.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to do what you need with just one CTE, using separate window functions for `ForecastDate` and `id`.

```sql
WITH ranked AS
(
        SELECT *, 
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ForecastDate DESC) AS rnk_dt,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ForecastDate ORDER BY id) AS rnk_id
    FROM mytable
)
SELECT * FROM ranked
WHERE rnk_dt = 2 AND rnk_id = 1
```

Of course, you can adjust the logic for the `id` as desired (e.g. pull the last ID instead of the first one). And we're using `DENSE_RANK` to handle ties as might be expected.

(fiddle [here](https://sqlfiddle.com/sql-server/online-compiler?id=61f254a5-75c7-47da-b50d-691c267a35d3)